# WordPress installation does not get completed in WAMP server

Tags: installation

I have installed [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) server on Windows 8 and am trying to install WordPress on it, but while installing it, I could not complete it. It's showing me the error like

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php?step=2
```

After that, the process stops.

I referred to the question *[Wordpress Installation not getting completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729658/wordpress-installation-not-getting-completed)*, but it could not help me.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I hope that what solved my problem will help you, in php.ini, I set the `max_execution_time` configuration to `90` instead of the default value `30`.

```
max_execution_time = 90
```

Answer (score 1):

That isn't an error. It is an URL, and it suggests that the problem is here:

> ```
> case 2:
>     if ( ! empty( $wpdb->error ) )
>         wp_die( $wpdb->error->get_error_message() );
> ```
>
> http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/install.php#L188

That is turn does suggest that you have a database error. Make sure that your database server is running and turn on error reporting. I don't use WAMP, but maybe these will help:

- Stack Overflow question *[Error logging with WAMP server in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230984/php-error-logging-with-wamp-server)*
- Blog post *[How to display PHP errors on your LAMP/WAMP setup](http://www.commondork.com/2010/05/21/how-to-display-php-errors-on-your-lampwamp-setup/)*
- Stack Overflow question *[Why won't Apache 2.1.7 in WAMP log PHP errors to the PHP error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095784/apache-2-1-7-in-wamp-wont-log-php-errors-to-php-error-log)*

Answer (score 0):

- delete **wp-config.php** file.
- than open installation page of wordpress.
- change database prefix, for example as **ex_**

Comment: Why do you think this will fix the problem?

Comment: This is not best way.but may be benefit for this issue.

Comment: Of course your advice is best solution for this problem.

Comment: That isn't really what I mean. I mean "Please explain the answer". You may well be right but _why_? Why do you think this will solve the problem and exactly what does this do? What are the dangers? What are the consequences? Provide more details.